# spree palypal express to work for recurring payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, spree

Is there a way to make the spree-paypal-express to work for recurring payments, I'm using spree 1.3 and I need to ship the order based on the option selected by the user like weekly or monthly, quarterly, etc..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this function does not exist within Spree itself.  You'll have to either find an extension which meets your needs or create your own extension.  You should read through the [Spree Extension Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html) for some helpful tips on where to start.